# JSON from PHP to Objective C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I have problem with UTF-8 symbols. I send data from PHP server to my app.

PHP code:

```
$json = json_encode ($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json;
```

Objective C code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_mutableData
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
    NSError * error=nil;
    NSDictionary * parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization 
        JSONObjectWithData:_mutableData
        options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", parsedData);
}
```

Objective C code will output:

```
{"name":"1sФ 女"}
```

And for second NSLog:

```
{
    name = "1s\U0424 \U5973";
}
```

If I remove `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option from PHP code I get this output:

```
{"name":"1s\u0424 \u5973"}
```

And for second NSLog:

```
{
    name = "1s\U0424 \U5973";
}
```

So, nothing really changed for me. How to get properly encoded string ("1sФ 女") in NSDictionary?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html).

Comment: @MaciejOczko thanks for good reading. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLog uses the description method for printing NSDictionary,
and that prints all non-ASCII characters in the escaped form.
NSLog is used mainly for debug so this should not be a problem as the NSDictionary contains the wanted unicode characters.

Comment: You are totally right. String is properly encoded when you output NSString object or put it in UILabel. Thanks.